# column full of NA using lapply in a data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I have a problem using `lapply` in a data.table. Here are two examples:

```
library(data.table)
 library(lubridate)

test <- function(x) 
{
  if(is.na(x)) return(NA)
  if(x=="") return(NA)
  if(substr(x,3,3)=="/") return(as_date(x,"%d/%m/%Y"))
  return(2)
}

x1<-data.table(v1=c("","07/06/2016","",NA), v2=c("2004-06-18","","2004-06-18","2004-06-18"))
x1[,lapply(.SD,test)]

x2<-data.table(v1=c("2004-06-19","2004-06-18","",NA),v2=c("2004-06-18","","2004-06-18","2004-06-18"))
x2[,lapply(.SD,test)]
```

In the first example, the first column after the `lapply` is full of `NA`, but I wanted to obtain is `NA, 2016-06-07, NA, NA`.

In the second example, the last two rows of the first column are wrong, because each row contains 2 but in my opinion should contains `NA`.

I don't understand how R considers the `NA` here. What do I miss to get what I want?

Comment: What is the `.SD` above?

Comment: This allows us to apply a function on all the columns. We can also put another parameter, ".SDcols = c(...)" to apply the function on specific columns. This is used for data tables only, I think.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries, the answer is that `data.table` considers columns as variables, and `.SD` is a list whose elements are the columns as variables, and so when applying a function, as test here, this function must take as argument a list.

Here is what you should change:

```
testList <- function(x) 
{
  lapply(x,test)
}

x1[,lapply(.SD,testList)]
```

If someone knows about another solution, please don't hesitate to share.

Answer (score 0):

First, I can't run your example without throwing an error. The second columns of your data.tables are of class "Date", but the `""` entry isn't a date. When it prints it's formatted to look like `NA`. Try running `is.na(x1$v2[2])` and `x1$v2[2] == ""`.

Also, it looks like you have a problem with vectorization.

Try running `test(x1$v1)`. Pay attention to the warning messages. `is.na(x)` returns a logical vector, but `if` only uses the first element in the vector.

```
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(x)) return(NA) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

You might be able to fix it by applying to each row:

```
x1[, lapply(.SD, test), by = 1:nrow(x1)]
```

Otherwise you'll need to modify your `test` function to accept a vector of strings and return a vector of results. But you should really consider returning a vector of a single type.

Finally, I don't understand the purpose of `lubridate` in this example. Why not use `as.Date(x,"%d/%m/%Y")`. What do you gain from `as_date`?

### Edit

You can rewrite your function to work on vectors:

```
test <- function(x) 
{
  ans <- rep.int(2, length(x))
  ans[is.na(x) | x == ""] <- NA
  dates <- grepl('../', x)
  ans[dates] <- as_date(x[dates], "%d/%m/%Y") 

  return(ans)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @joeyreid for you answer. You are right about the vectorization, as I said in my answer. It's too bad that the `by = 1:nrow(x1)` trick doesn't work, because doing 2 lapply is slow. Not on this short example, but on table I work with it is. If you know something that works, I'll be grateful ! At least, the `lubridate` was used for another purpose and I didn't change it in my example, but you're right, it's not particularly useful here